# Java: Why does my for loop cycle through one more time and then break after I try to break out of it the first time?

Tags: java, loops, printing, for-loop, break

Here is my code. It is for checking whether or not a string of text is a substring of another string of text.

```
public class Problem2
{
public boolean isSubstring(String T, String P)
{
    System.out.println("String T: " + T);
    System.out.println("String P: " + P);
    char[] arrayT = T.toCharArray();
    System.out.println("Array T: " + Arrays.toString(arrayT));
    System.out.println("Array T length: " + arrayT.length);
    char[] arrayP = P.toCharArray();
    System.out.println("Array P: " + Arrays.toString(arrayP));
    System.out.println("Array P length: " + arrayP.length);
    int consecutive = 0;
    boolean isTrue = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayT.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("i: " + i);
        System.out.println("Consecutive characters before comparison: " + consecutive);
        System.out.println("Letters in T left to be compared: " + (arrayT.length - i));
        System.out.println("Unmatched letters in array P: " + (arrayP.length - consecutive));
        if(arrayT.length - i < arrayP.length - consecutive)
        {
            System.out.println("isTrue: " + isTrue);
            System.out.println("Break #1");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("arrayT[i]: " + arrayT[i]);
        System.out.println("arrayP[consecutive]: " + arrayP[consecutive]);
        if(arrayT[i] == arrayP[consecutive])
        {
            consecutive += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            consecutive = 0;
        }
        System.out.println("Consecutive characters after comparison: " + consecutive);
        if(consecutive == arrayP.length)
        {
            System.out.println("Consecutive = Array P length, " + consecutive + " = " + arrayP.length);
            isTrue = true;
            System.out.println("isTrue: " + isTrue);
            System.out.println("Break #2");
            break;
        }
    }
    return isTrue;
}}
```

Here are my test results. As one will be able to see below, each of the tests cycles through the for loop twice before actually breaking and returning the boolean. Why does this happen and how can I fix it? Anyone's help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Test 1
String T: MINNESOTA
String P: INNE
Array T: [M, I, N, N, E, S, O, T, A]
Array T length: 9
Array P: [I, N, N, E]
Array P length: 4
i: 0
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 9
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: M
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 0
i: 1
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 8
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: I
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 1
i: 2
Consecutive characters before comparison: 1
Letters in T left to be compared: 7
Unmatched letters in array P: 3
arrayT[i]: N
arrayP[consecutive]: N
Consecutive characters after comparison: 2
i: 3
Consecutive characters before comparison: 2
Letters in T left to be compared: 6
Unmatched letters in array P: 2
arrayT[i]: N
arrayP[consecutive]: N
Consecutive characters after comparison: 3
i: 4
Consecutive characters before comparison: 3
Letters in T left to be compared: 5
Unmatched letters in array P: 1
arrayT[i]: E
arrayP[consecutive]: E
Consecutive characters after comparison: 4
Consecutive = Array P length, 4 = 4
isTrue: true
Break #2
    //Why does it break here, but continue to loop once again below before returning the boolean?

String T: MINNESOTA
String P: INNE
Array T: [M, I, N, N, E, S, O, T, A]
Array T length: 9
Array P: [I, N, N, E]
Array P length: 4
i: 0
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 9
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: M
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 0
i: 1
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 8
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: I
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 1
i: 2
Consecutive characters before comparison: 1
Letters in T left to be compared: 7
Unmatched letters in array P: 3
arrayT[i]: N
arrayP[consecutive]: N
Consecutive characters after comparison: 2
i: 3
Consecutive characters before comparison: 2
Letters in T left to be compared: 6
Unmatched letters in array P: 2
arrayT[i]: N
arrayP[consecutive]: N
Consecutive characters after comparison: 3
i: 4
Consecutive characters before comparison: 3
Letters in T left to be compared: 5
Unmatched letters in array P: 1
arrayT[i]: E
arrayP[consecutive]: E
Consecutive characters after comparison: 4
Consecutive = Array P length, 4 = 4
isTrue: true
Break #2
INNE is a substring of MINNESOTA: true


Test 2
String T: MINNESOTA
String P: INEN
Array T: [M, I, N, N, E, S, O, T, A]
Array T length: 9
Array P: [I, N, E, N]
Array P length: 4
i: 0
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 9
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: M
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 0
i: 1
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 8
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: I
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 1
i: 2
Consecutive characters before comparison: 1
Letters in T left to be compared: 7
Unmatched letters in array P: 3
arrayT[i]: N
arrayP[consecutive]: N
Consecutive characters after comparison: 2
i: 3
Consecutive characters before comparison: 2
Letters in T left to be compared: 6
Unmatched letters in array P: 2
arrayT[i]: N
arrayP[consecutive]: E
Consecutive characters after comparison: 0
i: 4
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 5
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: E
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 0
i: 5
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 4
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: S
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 0
i: 6
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 3
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
isTrue: false
Break #1
    //Why does it break here, but continue to loop once again below before returning the boolean?

String T: MINNESOTA
String P: INEN
Array T: [M, I, N, N, E, S, O, T, A]
Array T length: 9
Array P: [I, N, E, N]
Array P length: 4
i: 0
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 9
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: M
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 0
i: 1
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 8
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: I
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 1
i: 2
Consecutive characters before comparison: 1
Letters in T left to be compared: 7
Unmatched letters in array P: 3
arrayT[i]: N
arrayP[consecutive]: N
Consecutive characters after comparison: 2
i: 3
Consecutive characters before comparison: 2
Letters in T left to be compared: 6
Unmatched letters in array P: 2
arrayT[i]: N
arrayP[consecutive]: E
Consecutive characters after comparison: 0
i: 4
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 5
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: E
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 0
i: 5
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 4
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
arrayT[i]: S
arrayP[consecutive]: I
Consecutive characters after comparison: 0
i: 6
Consecutive characters before comparison: 0
Letters in T left to be compared: 3
Unmatched letters in array P: 4
isTrue: false
Break #1
INEN is a substring of MINNESOTA: false
```

Here are the test cases.

```
public class Problem2Test
{
/**
 * Test of isSubstring method, of class Problem2.
 */
@Test
public void testIsSubstring()
{
    System.out.println("Test 1");
    String T = "MINNESOTA";
    String P = "INNE";
    Problem2 instance = new Problem2();
    boolean expResult = true;
    boolean result = instance.isSubstring(T, P);
    System.out.println(P + " is a substring of " + T + ": " + instance.isSubstring(T, P));
    assertEquals(expResult, result);

    System.out.println("Test 2");
    T = "MINNESOTA";
    P = "INEN";
    Problem2 instance2 = new Problem2();
    expResult = false;
    result = instance.isSubstring(T, P);
    System.out.println(P + " is a substring of " + T + ": " + instance.isSubstring(T, P));
    assertEquals(expResult, result);}}
```

Comment: to "code" a block, highlight the block and hit ctrl-k, or hit the `{}` button in the editor. manual way: indent each line with at least 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Marc.

Answer (score 0):

Because you call `instance.isSubstring(T,P)` twice for "Test 1" - once to save the `result` variable and once in the `System.out` call.

Comment: Thank you Rob, I didn't realize I was printing out another iteration through the for loop by adding instance.isSubstring(T, P) to the System.out call. I thought I was just adding the boolean result of the call - either true or false.